# PHP class best practice to output a message

Tags: php, class, oop

I've been searching for a while but i could find only divided opinions, some of them extremely confusing.

What is the best practice for returning a message if there are certain conditions met?

For example i have a class which i want to output a message if there is no `$_GET` variable set - this is the class file:

```
<?php
class User{
    public $_name;

    public function getUser(){
        if(empty($_GET)){
            echo 'There\'s no user!';
            return;
        }
        //do something else
        return;
    } 
}
?>
```

And then this is the file in which i'm using that class:

```
<?php
$user = new User();
$user->getUser();
?>
```

As you can see for now i'm using `echo` inside of that `getUser()` method but i feel like that's a very bad practice :(. So basically is there a good practice? Or all practices are good as long as they work? And if there is a good practice can you please explain me why is it better than others?

Thank you! :D

Comment: general thumbs rule: a class return data so you when one call getUser, it is expected to receive user data. It is not job class to echo stuff (imo)

Comment: Hey @Ggg, so then basically i should check if the class->method returned something in my output page and if not then just display a message using if/else statements?

Comment: or getUser() could return null if no data is outputted. That way you know that if it return null it is invalid

Comment: the other reason to let class deal with data stuff is that maybe in the future you will want to use your User class in let say your Company class.

Comment: Hey @Ggg, i think you should've write this as an answer X_X

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is also based on the application.

In your example I should return a exception.
At the top of your application you can run a try/catch to handle the exceptions.

For example

```
<?php
class User{
    public $_name;

    public function getUser(){
        if(empty($_GET)){
            throw new Exception("There is no User");
        }
        //do something else
        return;
    } 
}
?>
```

And finally:

```
<?php
try {
    $user = new User();
    $user->getUser();
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The benefit is, that you can handle messages at one location and that its easier to do something with error messages, for example

```
echo "<strong>". $exception->getMessage(). "</strong>";
```

**Edit:** The same reason what @Ggg said:

> general thumbs rule: a class return data so you when one call getUser,
>   it is expected to receive user data. It is not job class to echo stuff
>   (imo) – Ggg

If you don't want make use of a try/catch module I suggest that you don't echo a message when it occurs, but return a boolean or a message. With the same reasons as above: Handle messages at one place.
For example

```
<?php
class User{
    public $_name;

    public function getUser(){
        if(empty($_GET)){
            return 'no user found'
        }
        //do something else
        return;
    }

    public function login(){
        if(empty($_GET)){
            return false
        }
        //do something else
        return;
    } 
}
?>
```

And finally:

```
<?php
$user = new User();
echo $user->getUser();
// OR (and I think better):
if (!$user->login()) {
    echo 'Invalid login';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey @Martijn, thank you for taking time to answer! I'm a little dizzy after reading this and i can only conclude that there is no 'one perfect way'. Is that the right thing to understand? O_O

Comment: Hi Emma, What @Ggg also said is most time the best method: handle the output on one place. Because, when u use OOP. You have an class that handles the output. (Single responsibility). The ouput can than make suitable for the situation. For example: Send the output as a mail or print it on a webpage or whatever.

But if it's (for example) a very short application (with very few classes) or a CommandLine application, than sometime s is it's not always bad practice to use the echo at the moment of used. I hope this comment helps

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this, but the comments from Ggg and the answer from Martijn are good ones. I think it would be good form to accept this answer from Martijn as correct.

Comment: Dear @Martijn, it helps :D annnnnnd thank you for helping me, now it started to make sense :D